# How to remove spaces from file to make one long line?

Tags: python, file, spaces

I want to read a file and remove the spaces. I swear I've done this multiple times, but some reason the method I used to use doesn;t seem to be working. I must be making some small mistake somewhere, so I decided to make a small practice file (because the files I actually need to use are EXTREMELY LARGE) to find out.

the original file says:

abcdefg
(new line)
hijklmn

but I want it to say:
abcdefghijklmn

```
file = open('please work.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
  lines = line.strip()
  print(lines)
close.file()
```

However, it just says:
abcdefg
(new line)
hijklmn

and when I use line.strip('\n') it says:
abcdefg
(big new line)
hijklmn

Any help will be greatly appreciated, because this was the first thing I learned and suddenly I can't remember how to use it!

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is to concatenate each line into a single line, you could utilize rstrip and concatenate to a result variable:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = ''
    for line in fin:
        stripped_line = line.rstrip()
        lines += stripped_line
    print(lines)
```

From a text file looking like this:

```
abcdefg hijklmnop
this is a line
```

The result would be `abcdefg hijklmnopthis is a line`. If you did want to remove the whitespace as well you could `lines = lines.replace(' ','')` after the loop which would result in `abcdefghijklmnopthisisaline`.

Answer (score 0):

The (new line) in your output is from the `print`, which will output a `\n`. you can use `print(lines, end='')` to remove it.

Comment: thank you so much! I was able to copy and paste the """ print(lines, end='') ''''' directly into my script and it worked without a problem!

Answer (score 0):

`strip()` only removes leading & trailing spaces.

You can use `string.replace(' ', '')` to remove all spaces.

```
'abcdefg (new line) hijklmn'.replace(' ', '')
```

---

If your file has `tab` `newline` or other forms of spaces, the above will not work and you will need to use `regex` to remove all forms of space in the file.

```
import re
string = '''this is a \n
test \t\t\t
\r
\v

'''

re.sub(r'\s', '', string)
#'thisisatest'
```